# Spring request mapping to a different method for a particular path variable value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/authors")
public class AuthorController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Author getAuthor(
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response,
        @PathVariable final String id)
    {
        // Returns a single Author by id
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/author-properties", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public AuthorProperties getAuthorProperties(
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response,
        @PathVariable final String id)
    {
        // Returns a single Author's List of properties
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping // How to map /authors/*/author-properties to this method ????
    public List<AuthorProperties> listAuthorProperties(
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        // Returns a single Author's List of properties
        return null;
    }
}

class Author {
    String propertiesUri;
    // other fields
}

class AuthorProperties {
    String authorUri;
    // other fields
}
```

Basically I need:

- /authors - listing all the authors
- /authors/123 - fetching author by id 123
- /authors/123/author-properties - fetching the AuthorProperties object for a 123 author
- /authors/*/author-properties - fetching List of AuthorProperties for all authors

When I tried

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*/author-properties", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

It was still mapping `/authors/*/author-properties` to getAuthorProperties method with path variable value as "*".

Comment: When I kept the method for /*/author-properties before the method for /{id}/author-properties then it started working. So is it a proper solution? Can we always relay on the order of processing of the mappings as the order of method declaration?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id:.*}/author-properties", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can constraint the mapping for individual author using regular expressions, such as:

```
@RequestMapping("/{authorId:\\d+}/author-properties")
public String authorProperties(@PathVariable String authorId) {}
```

This will only match URLs where the author ID is numeric.

For the request for all author properties you can use:

```
@RequestMapping("/*/author-properties")
public String allProperties() { }
```

Hovewer `*` has special meaning so it will match `/foo/author-properties` also. To work around it you can use something like:

```
@RequestMapping("/{all:\\*}/author-properties")
public String allProperties() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

If fetching List of AuthorProperties for all authors is common case, then I think that you should make an URI like this: "/author-properties". Otherwise answer given by Bohuslav is what you want.