# Default request mapping method picked up for other URLs with Path variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have a `@RestController` below as below. The method `getTrain(long)` is supposed to be picked up for URLs `http://localhost:8080/trains/1` but instead it's picking up `getTrains()`. The other URLs work fine as expected. I am not sure if I am missing or not understanding something. I also looked at [Spring request mapping to a different method for a particular path variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821875/spring-request-mapping-to-a-different-method-for-a-particular-path-variable-valu)
 and it helped a bit.

Requirements:
1. /trains [POST] - add train
2. /trains [GET] - get all trains
3. /trains/{trainId} - get train by id

```
@RestController
public class TrainController {

    @Autowired
    private TrainService trainService;

    @RequestMapping(headers = { "Accept=application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public TrainDto addTrain(@RequestBody TrainDto trainDto) throws Exception {

        return trainService.addTrain(trainDto);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<TrainDto> getTrains() throws Exception {

        return trainService.getTrains();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{trainId:\\d+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public TrainDto getTrain(@PathVariable("trainId") long trainId) throws Exception {

        return trainService.getTrain(trainId);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `"/{trainId:\\d+}` by appending a `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add **value = ""** to mapping request. See if this works

```
@RestController public class TrainController {

    @Autowired
    private TrainService trainService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/trains",headers = { "Accept=application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public TrainDto addTrain(@RequestBody TrainDto trainDto) throws Exception {

        return trainService.addTrain(trainDto);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/trains",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<TrainDto> getTrains() throws Exception {

        return trainService.getTrains();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/trains/{trainId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public TrainDto getTrain(@PathVariable("trainId") long trainId) throws Exception {

        return trainService.getTrain(trainId);
    }

}
```

Or you can do it this way.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(TrainController.REQUEST_MAPPING_URL)
public class TrainController {

       public static final String REQUEST_MAPPING_URL = "/trains";

        @Autowired
        private TrainService trainService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/",headers = { "Accept=application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public TrainDto addTrain(@RequestBody TrainDto trainDto) throws Exception {
            return trainService.addTrain(trainDto);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<TrainDto> getTrains() throws Exception {
            return trainService.getTrains();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{trainId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public TrainDto getTrain(@PathVariable("trainId") long trainId) throws Exception {
            return trainService.getTrain(trainId);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi, this is a train app. So the URL already has trains to it. Doing it like this would result in /trains/trains/{trainId}

Comment: I cannot see it in your code. where are you put "/trains" ?

Comment: Wow, I tried it and it worked. Can you may be explain why it is not also appending the app name as part of the root url?

Comment: Both worked. I forgot that with Spring boot apps, the context path does not default to the app name

Comment: @FourtyTwo then you can accept as right answer. The HTTP method parameter has no default – so if we don’t specify a value, it’s going to map to any HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
public class TrainController {

    @Autowired
    private TrainService trainService;

    @RequestMapping(headers = { "Accept=application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public TrainDto addTrain(@RequestBody TrainDto trainDto) throws Exception {

        return trainService.addTrain(trainDto);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<TrainDto> getTrains() throws Exception {

        return trainService.getTrains();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{trainId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public TrainDto getTrain(@PathVariable("trainId") long trainId) throws Exception {

        return trainService.getTrain(trainId);
    }
}
```

This would work. The value inside curly braces i.e. trainId should map to PathVariable.